# How to access data that an offset of a register in gdb?

Tags: memory, gdb

How can I access a value such as `0x14(%edx)`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
x/16xb $edx+0x14
```

The `+0x14` will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day!

Comment: Thanks men that was what I wanted! :)