# How to access data that an offset of a register in gdb with disp?

Tags: memory, gdb

How can I access a value such as 0x14(%edx) using the display command instead of examine?

Just like the question here, except I'd like to use disp so that the displayed value is updated as I step through the program:

[How to access data that an offset of a register in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887162/how-to-access-data-that-an-offset-of-a-register-in-gdb)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
(gdb) display *(int*)(0x14 + $edx)
```